# How can I display category description in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to display the category description in WordPress, but I want to display it where I want, not only below the category name.

```
<?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
<h3 class="omc-blog-one-cat">
    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); echo ('/?cat='.$category[0]->term_id); ?>">
        <?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>
    </a>
</h3>
```

I want to display the category description after this category name.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use it with the `category_description($category_id)` function

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description)

Answer (score 0):

```
$category_description = category_description();
                if ( ! empty( $category_description ) )
                echo $category_description;
```